# Issue in calculating balance from debit and credit in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL v5.7
I need to calculate running balance form debit and credit columns. the mention query works perfectly but when i restrict the rows in where condition it shows wrong values. actually it calculates the sum for all rows and then show the results of required rows but in that case the required balance goes worng.
here is my query that works when i fetch all rows.

```
SELECT
    vch.TR_ID,
  vch.TR_CUST_ID,
    vch.TR_DEBIT Debit,
    vch.TR_CREDIT Credit,
    COALESCE ((SELECT SUM(TR_CREDIT) - SUM(TR_DEBIT) FROM  all_trans vch2 WHERE vch2.TR_ID <= vch.TR_ID ),0 ) AS Balance,
    vch.TR_DATETIME DateTime
FROM    `falcondb`.`all_trans` vch
WHERE
vch.TR_DATETIME BETWEEN 
STR_TO_DATE('2020-07-24 11:19:18','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')AND 
STR_TO_DATE('2020-10-24 11:19:18','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
ORDER BY vch.TR_ID;
```

---

This is transaction table having CUST_ID and my primary key is TR_ID
I have some other attached tables which will be joined with this but here they doesn't matter. that's why I didn't show here in order to make it simple for you guys.
Screen shots of both conditions attached.
[image: query with all rows]
[image: query for specific cust_id]

---

What my sub query actually do is: it calculate it for all entries in the table and shows me only with cust_id=1. that's the actual problem. it must calculate the balance for the selected rows only. it actually calculates for all rows and show me the rows from that result. the below screenshot explains it

[image: This is actually my query do when I put condition for Cust_id]

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: version of mysql is 5.7

Comment: Str_to_date is redundant in this context

Comment: @Strawberry dear , is it considerable here ? i can remove it  but issue is not here. actually I am sending this parameter from C# to the query as a string that's why I have to do this.

Comment: Pls show the expected results for the 2nd query because its results are obviously in line with the query and we do not really know what you are after!

Comment: If your complaint is that the balance is right but shows on the wrong line, change the `<=` into `<` in the subquery that sums the debits and credits

Comment: @Shadow dear: my results in the second query are wrong as 2 debit entries must have minus values. I want to minus the debit from credit , just have a look it seems to be common sense math's I think.

Comment: Your comment in response to mine makes no sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a per-`TR_CUST_ID` balance, then you need to include a correlation clause on that column in the subquery:

```
SELECT
    vch.TR_ID,
    vch.TR_CUST_ID,
    vch.TR_DEBIT Debit,
    vch.TR_CREDIT Credit,
    COALESCE (
        (
            SELECT SUM(TR_CREDIT) - SUM(TR_DEBIT) 
            FROM all_trans vch2 
            WHERE vch2.TR_ID <= vch.TR_ID AND vch2.TR_CUST_ID = vch.TR_CUST_ID
        ),                                  --^-- here
        0 
    ) AS Balance,
    vch.TR_DATETIME DateTime
FROM all_trans vch
WHERE 
    vch.TR_CUST_ID = 1
    AND vch.TR_DATETIME BETWEEN '2020-07-24 11:19:18' AND '2020-10-24 11:19:18'
ORDER BY vch.TR_ID;
```

Note that I removed the `STR_TO_DATE()` expressions: they are not needed, since the values that you have are perfectly valid literal dates in MySQL already.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear. it worked and also thanks for datetime format correction.